# How do I generate a random, 10 character long, sequence of upper letters, lower letters, numbers and some symbols?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

Want to make a random sequence of letters, numbers and allowed symbols ("^","*","$","!","%","&","(",")","-","_","=","+") that is 10 characters long (supposedly making a perfect password), but can't do it! Here's what I got so far:

```
import random
password="##########"
#Pick Length
pwordLen = random.randint(8,24)

lowerConsonants = ("b","c","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","m","n","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","x","y","z")
upperConsonants = ("B","C","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","M","N","P","Q","R","S","T","V","W","X","Y","Z")
lowerVowels = ("a","e","u","o","i")
upperVowels=("A","E","U","O","I")
numbers = ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
symbols = ("^","*","$","!","%","&","(",")","-","_","=","+")

#For character 1 of 24
selectType1=random.randint(1,6)
if selectType1==1 or selectType1==2:
    selectIndividual1=random.randint(1,26)
    selectIndividual1=selectIndividual1-1
elif selectType1==3 or selectType1==4:
    selectIndividual1=random.randint(1,5)
    selectIndividual1=selectIndividual1-1
elif selectType1==5:
    selectIndividual1=random.randint(1,10)
    selectIndividual1=selectIndividual1-1
else:
    selectIndividual1=random.randint(1,12)
    selectIndividual1=selectIndividual1-1

if selectType1==1:
    password[0]=lowerConsonants[selectIndividual1]
elif selectType1==2 :
    password[0]=upperConsonants[selectIndividual1]
elif selectType1==3 :
    password[0]=lowerVowels[selectIndividual1]
elif selectType1==4 :
    password[0]=upperVowels[selectIndividual1]
elif selectType1==5 :
    password[0]=numbers[selectIndividual1]
else:
    password[0]=symbols[selectIndividual1]

print(password)
```

I was then gonna replace all that 'selectIndividual1' and 'selectType1' for every number through to 10, then merge those 10 characters to form my string.

At the moment I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/_____/Documents/temp5.py", line 34, in <module>
password[0]=lowerVowels[selectIndividual1]
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I'm on Mac, running Python 3.7.0

Comment: Do you understand what the error message is saying to you?

Answer (score 2):

With random and string library :

```
import string
import random

all_char = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation + string.digits
password = "".join(random.choice(all_char) for x in range(random.randint(10)))

//Y+QV9dXGSh
//G?|Q5i?0\\c
```

**EDIT**

String sets are:

```
string.letters:
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

string.punctuation:
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~

string.digits:
0123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution:

```
import string
import random
pwd = []
for i in range(10):
    r = random.choice(string.letters + string.punctuation + string.digits)
    pwd.append(r)
print ''.join(pwd)
```

Output:

```
xS1]O3_z~I
```

Printing `string.letters`,`string.punctuation` and `string.digits`:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
0123456789
```

Comment: I will use your print string hint

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, as stated, in python one is not allowed to edit a `str` object.  They are "immutable".  The way to overcome this is to just add up your individual characters:  `pass = pass + selected_char` (which doesn't alter the pass object, it builds an all new one).

e.g.

```
password = ""
# your char picking logic here
if selectType == 1:
    password += lowerConsonants[selectIndividual]
# the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `random.choice`

```
>>> import random
>>> all_chars = lowerConsonants + upperConsonants + lowerVowels + upperVowels + numbers+ symbols
>>> ''.join([random.choice(all_chars) for i in range(10)])
'W+8yB533$W'
```

Comment: This creates a similar password, but will not draw them from the same distribution as the OP's current logic.  Not that I think the OP cares, I'm just a pedant.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save an array element into a String, hence the error.

Change this:

```
password="##########"
#Pick Length
pwordLen = random.randint(8,24)
```

To this:

```
#Pick Length
pwordLen = random.randint(8,24)
password=[pwordLen]
```